# Use keyword replacement from core php to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use core php library in codeigniter. After inculding files in php code, It contain code as:

```
use Mylib\Configuration\GenericConfiguration;
use Mylib\Operations\Search;
```

I am getting error on using 'use' keyword and I am not able to find how to use this files in codeigniter code. So, Please help me to find solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which folder you located these two `library`...?

Comment: Mylib is a folder available in same folder in which php file is available.

Comment: i am asking where you located `Mylib` folder in `codeigniter` folder structure. and what content you have inside php file such as `functions` only ..?

Comment: Mylib folder is created in root folder parallel to application folder.

Comment: inside php file only functions you created ..?

Comment: You can go with `core folder` if you implemented `classes` otherwise you can use inside `helper files`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try with that

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CodeIgniter libraries** that might help you to avoid **use** keyword

In CodeIgniter, libraries folder is available in

```
[CI_ROOT]/application/libraries/
```

For this simply place your all **Mylib\Configuration\GenericConfiguration, Mylib\Operations\Search** class files into the libraries folder

Then, you can mention these libraries in autoload.php (**[CI_ROOT]/application/config/autoload.php**) as

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','[Your_Library_Class Name_In_Small_Letters]');
```

or, if you want to use in a specific controller or in a specific method, use like

```
$this->load->library('[Your_Library_Class_Name_In_Small_Letters]');
```

after doing this, you can call your library functions with its instance like

```
$this->[Your_Library_Class Name_In_Small_Letters]->libraryFunctionName();
```

See [Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html) for brief explanation.